# Orange data Table

Tags: python, numpy, datatable, orange

I have a numpy array of numpy arrays and I want to run association rules mining on them by using Orange. How can I convert numpy arrays to Orange data Table?

Regarding this link https://orange3-associate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html#fpgrowth.frequent_itemsets I tried to do it with the function:fpgrowth.frequent_itemsets(X, min_support=0.2)
but I can not install fpgrowth package on my windows machin.

PS: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to be a bit more clear? If I'm correct you have two questions:

**Creation of a data table from numpy:**

The documentation gives you an example (https://docs.orange.biolab.si/2/reference/rst/Orange.data.table.html):

```
import numpy
d = Orange.data.Domain([Orange.feature.Continuous('a%i' % x) for x in range(5)])
a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]])
t = Orange.data.Table(a)
```

**Installation of orange3-associate**

The link provided in your post points to the documentation for Orange 3 (Python 3) but you are using Python 2. Can you provide a reference to this package for Python 2?